# Do I need other libraries than React.js to work with databases

Tags: database, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I just started learning react. Now I want to build a small application where:

1. A user can Register/Log In (working with database)
2. The user can add items to a todo list
3. The todo list is stored in a database

Do I need other libraries to work with databases?

It's a small application.

Should I use Redux or rather something using MVC pattern like ASP.net?

I don't have any expierence with any of these. After lot of research I am still clueless on where to start with.

Comment: That depends entirely on which database you want to use, and how it is accessed. If the database has a REST API, you may not need anything else.

Comment: I prefer oracle SQL or mysql. I don't know what REST is but I'll look into it. Guess there is a learning curve.

Comment: For most RDBMSs, such as Oracle or MySQL, you will generally need a server that serves as an intermediary between your React application, and the database. This intermediary will essentially provide a REST (or similar) API to your React application.

Comment: As you can tell, though, this is a pretty involved thing... a lot bigger than a typical SO answer can handle :)

Comment: So I can use the XAMPP or LAMP stack for this?

Comment: Sure, XAMPP or LAMP, or any other of the literally infinite stacks out there, could do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As you are a beginner. I would recommend you to use below libraries in both front-end and backend to start with your application

Front-end:

1. React - works as view layer
2. axios - to talk to backend database for all CRUD operations
3. Use localstorage or session storage to work between components. Because your application is very small so you can go with this approach or consider
   using redux from now if you feel your application will grow bigger in
   future

Back-end:

1. Keep your back end service as micro-services
2. As you are already working on react means you know something about javascript so I recommend you write your backend service in nodejs
3. If you want to use No SQL database then you can go with mongoDB database using mongoose in nodejs
4. If you prefer SQL database then I would recommend you to start with Postgres SQL database. Postgres SQL is popular these days than
   any other SQL database

These are the required libraries for you to start.

I would recommend you to go for MERN stack i.e., MongoDB, Express JS, ReactJS and NodeJS